# Regex: Find and modify multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have a `HTML` string which contains some `img` tags. I have to find and modify `src` attribute in each `img` tag. e.g.

The original tag is:

```
<img src="http://some.domain.com/images/uncat-images/?file=vx1qro62da5th39u.jpeg&dimension=50" style="color:#2345f1" />
```

which I want to get the `file` query string's value, map it in some code, get the new name, and modify the whole `src` attribute with a new one.

e.g. in the given example, the `file` name is `vx1qro62da5th39u.jpeg`. So, I want it to find the new value from a map. for example, it will be `newfilename.png`. now I want to replace the whole `src` value with this:

```
/newroot/images/newfilename.png
```

Which means to `img` should look like this:

```
<img src="/newroot/images/newfilename.png" style="color:#2345f1" />
```

I have this `Regex` which gives me the `src` value in a named group:

```
var regex = new Regex("<img.+?src=[\\\"'](?<URL>.+?)[\\\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

To be honest, I'm stuck right here for about 2 hours ):

```
var regex = new Regex("<img.+?src=[\\\"'](?<URL>.+?)[\\\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var html = "My html string with several img tags...";
var matches = regex.Matches(html);
foreach (Match match in matches){
     // I'm right here ):       
}
```

Does any body know how to continue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method using [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Example:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("(?<=<img[^>]*src=\")[^\"]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string html = "My html string with several img tags...";
string newHtml = rx.Replace(html, m => "/newroot/images/" + m.Value);
```

I modified your regex using positive lookbehind so it captures only content of *src* attribute.